# 2.8 Preference Menu

Tags: interface, customization

My user preference menu is completely different from the 2.8 manual, checked on youtubers and other posts, they have the right menu. I can't find anything.

How do I change this menu? Is it updated recently? There is NO options for ANYTHING in the preference menu.

Right now i'm trying to find the cursor depth toggle, which is usually in the interface tab.

Please help me, I am desperate.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 2.8 is still in beta, It is changing constantly. It is likely that some of the references you are using have different interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Cursor Project]

Turning off Cursor Project might be what you are looking for. The 3D Cursor is now a wholly different beast, though. It is bound to have different settings.

Comment: It was off already, but it worked when enabled it! Thank you so much :D Been causing me major headache.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Don't forget to mark the answer if it DID work.